# Creating a priority stream in reactive extensions and ignoring second stream

Tags: system.reactive

I have two observables where they each do something different.  I want the second stream to ignore its inputs if their first stream has received some data within some time interval, let's say 500ms.  How would I go about doing this?

```
var s1 = new Subject<string>();
var s2 = new Subject<string>();

s1.Subscribe(x => Debug.Write(x));                
//Subscribe something slightly different
s2.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));


s1.OnNext("foo");
Thread.Sleep(500);
s2.OnNext("bar");

/* Expected output:
    * foobar /r/n
    */

s1.OnNext("fizz");
s2.OnNext("buzz");
/* Expected output:
* fizz
*/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will start a timer everytime `s1` produces a value.  Whenever that timer is running, it will unsubscribe from `s2` and resubscribe when the timer expires:

```
var delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
var s2lowPriority = s1
    .Select(_ => Observable.Timer(delay).SelectMany(_ => s2))
    .StartWith(s2)
    .Switch();

s2lowPriority.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: That's a neat solution.